# Send list of Object to web service c#.Net with ksoap2

Tags: android, asp.net, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

Hi all I m programming on an Android Application that should be able to send a complex object to c#.Net webservice so the problem is i can send a single object but i cant send a list of object , my question is how to send a list of objects to web service 
for more detail or if u want my source code just inform me thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My sugestion is, you can send the list of objetc in XML like a single string and in the server side you can get this string and transform in xml again. This works for me.